# Integral w.r.t. a Martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Consider the stochastic integral

$$
Z_t = 1+\int_0^tZ_{s^{-}}\,dX_s
$$

where $X$ is a Martingale. In the textbook by Shreve (see [here](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9780387401010) pages 493-493) it is said that since $Z_{s^{-}}$ is left-continuous and the integrator $X$ is a martingale then $Z_t$ is a martingale. 
I cannot figure out why this should be the case, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, one can show that for any p > 1, and bounded predictable integrand, the stochastic integral preserves the space of p-integrable martingales. 
If your process is a bounded left-continuous process, then it holds. You could have more info on the following link : 
https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality/